# type matching error in tensor

Tags: numpy, tensorflow

I am following a [Tensorflow example](https://github.com/matthieule/unet_tensorflow/blob/master/main.ipynb). However, running the code gives me the following error message.

It seems to me that the following code segment causes the problem. Or the last dimension of `h_conv10` has `float64`. But there is no place where `float64` is setup explicitly. Thank you for the suggestions and hints.

```
# Deconvolution 1
W_deconv_1 = weight_variable_devonc([max_pool_size, max_pool_size, 8*chanel_root, 16*chanel_root])
b_deconv1 = bias_variable([8*chanel_root])
h_deconv1 = tf.nn.relu(deconv2d(h_conv10, W_deconv_1, max_pool_size) + b_deconv1)
h_deconv1_concat = crop_and_concat(h_conv8,h_deconv1,[n_image,(((nx-180)/2+4)/2+4)/2+4,(((ny-180)/2+4)/2+4)/2+4,8*chanel_root])





python u-net.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "/experiment/tfw/lib/python3.4/site-  
packages/tensorflow/python/ops/op_def_library.py", line 377, in apply_op
  as_ref=input_arg.is_ref)
File "/experiment/tfw/lib/python3.4/site-  
packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 608, in convert_n_to_tensor
ret.append(convert_to_tensor(value, dtype=dtype, name=n, as_ref=as_ref))
File "/experiment/tfw/lib/python3.4/site-
packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 566, in convert_to_tensor
   ret = conversion_func(value, dtype=dtype, name=name, as_ref=as_ref)
File "/experiment/tfw/lib/python3.4/site-  
packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 510, in 
_TensorTensorConversionFunction
% (dtype.name, t.dtype.name, str(t)))

ValueError: Tensor conversion requested dtype int32 for Tensor with dtype 
float64: 'Tensor("truediv:0", shape=(), dtype=float64)'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "u-net.py", line 193, in <module>
h_deconv1 = tf.nn.relu(deconv2d(h_conv10, W_deconv_1, max_pool_size) + b_deconv1)
File "u-net.py", line 77, in deconv2d
output_shape = tf.pack([tf.shape(x)[0], tf.shape(x)[1]*2, tf.shape(x)[2]*2, tf.shape(x)[3]/2])
File "/experiment/tfw/lib/python3.4/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/array_ops.py", line 241, in pack
return gen_array_ops._pack(values, name=name)
File "/experiment/tfw/lib/python3.4/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gen_array_ops.py", line 916, in _pack
return _op_def_lib.apply_op("Pack", values=values, name=name)
File "/experiment/tfw/lib/python3.4/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/op_def_library.py", line 396, in apply_op
raise TypeError("%s that don't all match." % prefix)
TypeError: Tensors in list passed to 'values' of 'Pack' Op have types [int32, int32, int32, float64] that don't all match.
```

Comment: `float64` is the default type for numpy, so you can get that type on conversion from number like 1.

Comment: Hi Yaroslav, can you elaborate more? In the code, h_conv10 = tf.nn.relu(conv2d(h_conv9, W_conv10,keep_prob) + b_conv10).  According to the error message, the first three dimension of h_conv10 is int32, and the last one is float64. How to transfer it to int32 for matching purposes? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Can you replace your `/` with `//` ? You seem to be using Python 3 where integer division gives a floating point result

Comment: Yes, it removes the error messages. Thank you very much.